# PHP class not found but autoload included

Tags: php

So, I'm trying to write this backend php application, but keep getting

```
Class 'backend\core\router\HttpRouter' not found
```

I've tried everything. My files are as followed:
[file layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5j41.png)

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "backend\\core\\common\\": "backend/core_common/",
        "backend\\core\\router\\": "backend/core_router/core/main/",
        "backend\\core\\router\\lib\\": "backend/core_router/core/lib/"
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $router = new \backend\core\router\HttpRouter();
    $router->run();
} catch (\throwable $exception) {
    echo 'SERVER ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

The HttpRouter has the namespace:

```
namespace backend\core\router;
```

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: Are you using composer?

Comment: Yes I am! I did run composer install

Comment: Does the `HttpRouter` class have the correct namespace?

Comment: It does! I added it to the original post

Comment: what happens if you run `composer dump-autoload` in your command line?

Comment: Still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your autoload path.

```
"backend\\core\\router\\": "backend/core_router/core/main/",
```

Per your image it should be:

```
"backend\\core\\router\\": "backend/core_router/code/main/",
```

Note the `code`, not `core`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1. remove the backslash in the front of initiating the class: "new backend\core\router\HttpRouter();"
2. regenerate the composer cache file: "composer dump-autoload"